# Example of a group whose order is a perfect number with a "perfect" class equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am interested in finding an example of a group G whose order is a perfect number and whose class equation is likewise "perfect". For example it could be a group of order 6 whose class equation looks like: 1 + 2 + 3.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect class equation"? That the terms in the class equation are exactly the divisors of the order of the group?

Comment: Did you try $S_3$?

Comment: Paul, what a "perfect" example! And yes Arthur that is what I meant.

Comment: I mean, what did you try befor asking this question? $S_3$ is like the first group of order $6$ that comes to my mind.

Comment: I actually tried nothing haha. For some reason I thought it would be difficult to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paul K points out,  $S_3$ should be one.  The conjugacy classes are $\{e\}$, $\{(123),(132)\}$ and $\{(12),(13),(23)\}$